# Xubuntu Xenial 16.04.3 LTS Completely Freezes when I start Virtualbox 5.0.40_Ubuntu r115130

Tags: 16.04, virtualbox, xubuntu, crash

I installed VirtualBox a couple weeks back on a System76 Gazelle Professional I have and created a few VMs.  Everything had been running smooth until yesterday when I booted my laptop.  Every time I go to start a VM, the computer completely freezes.  I can't hit right-ctrl F1, the fan just spins up and I get nothing. Hard powered off, rebooted, let it hang overnight hoping for a crash.  Nothing.

Tried to uninstall everything

```
sudo apt-get remove virtualbox* --purge
sudo rm ~/"VirtualBox VMs" -Rf
sudo rm ~/.config/VirtualBox/ -Rf
```

Reinstalled and created a brand new VM.  Same problem.  No idea what I could do in order to get metrics a la a crash dump or why this is happening.

Uname -a

```
Linux aps 4.13.0-31-generic #34~16.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Fri Jan 19 17:11:01 UTC 2018 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

dkms status

```
virtualbox, 5.0.40, 4.13.0-31-generic, x86_64: installed
```

dpkg -l *virtualbox* | grep ii

```
ii  virtualbox                     5.0.40-dfsg-0ubuntu1.16.04.2 amd64        x86 virtualization solution - base binaries
ii  virtualbox-dkms                5.0.40-dfsg-0ubuntu1.16.04.2 all          x86 virtualization solution - kernel module sources for dkms
ii  virtualbox-qt                  5.0.40-dfsg-0ubuntu1.16.04.2 amd64        x86 virtualization solution - Qt based user interface
```

Comment: As per dpkg -l, you are getting virtual box version 5.0.40 as the latest. But currently 5.2.6 is the latest version. Kindly consider to manually download and install the same. https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Linux_Downloads

Comment: You may like to refer the change log. https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Changelog. I hope this should solve the problem.

Comment: @Aravind I added the deb and 5.2 does work.  Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue with the latest kernel available: 4.13.0-36.
So I have reverted to using the latest kernel that *works* without any issues: 4.11.0-14

```
$ aptitude search 4.11.0-14 | grep ^i
i A linux-headers-4.11.0-14         - Header files related to Linux kernel versi
i   linux-headers-4.11.0-14-generic - Linux kernel headers for version 4.11.0 on
iBA linux-hwe-edge-tools-4.11.0-14  - Linux kernel version specific tools for ve
i   linux-image-4.11.0-14-generic   - Linux kernel image for version 4.11.0 on 6
i   linux-image-extra-4.11.0-14-gen - Linux kernel extra modules for version 4.1
i   linux-signed-image-4.11.0-14-ge - Signed kernel image generic               
i   linux-tools-4.11.0-14-generic   - Linux kernel version specific tools for ve
```

I let the latest kernel be, so that I continue to get upgrades, and whenever I boot the system I select the 4.11.0-14 version by entering the grub menu.

Every now and then, when there are updates in new kernel versions, I test whether this has been fixed. No success so far.